# Laravel Echo join, get the current user object

Tags: laravel-echo

Is there a way to get the current user data when is joinning a channel?

```
  Echo.join('channel')
    .here((users) => {
      this.users = users;
      this.user = ???
    })
```

I'm currently going through an ajax request to retrieve the user's session.

Thanks a lot

Comment: did you get an answer for this?? I am stuck at a wall with this

Comment: no still using a specific request. i'm also hoping a better solution. if the configuration allows it, you can always pass the user object to the view/component.